# JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType Bypass Array

Tags: c#, json.net

I wrote a wrapper to handle how my app interacts with a 3rd party API that uses a generic to de-serialize onto:

```
protected static async Task<TResult> Get<TResult, TApiModel>(string url, Dictionary<string, string> additionalHeaders = null)
        where TResult : IBaseModel, new()
        where TApiModel : IBaseApiResult<TResult>, new()
{
    var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ...
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    try
    {
        var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, new TApiModel());
        var model = deserializedObject.ConvertToBaseModel();
        return model;
    }
    catch { ... }
}
```

The version I was using was originally using was returning a "flat" objects as a result like this:

```
{
    "_id": 44322889,
    "bio": "...",
    "created_at": "2013-06-03T19:12:02Z",
    "display_name": "...",
}
```

That version was recently deprecated and the new version now returns all responses wrapped in a data array even for singular responses like this:

```
data: [{
    "_id": 44322889,
    "bio": "...",
    "created_at": "2013-06-03T19:12:02Z",
    "display_name": "...",
}]
```

Is there a way to update my the above deserialize code so I don't have to update all of the classes which utilize this?

Comment: Why are you using `DeserializeAnonymousType` when your type isn't anonymous? Try `return DeserializeObject<TApiModel[]>(data)?.FirstOrDefault()?.ConvertToBaseModel();`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Firstly, yes I should not have been using `AnonymousType` - thank you for this, I didn't know I could do that. Unfortunately, I am getting an error when I tried your suggestion because the TApiModel array is under the property "data" in the response. `"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type ...  because the type requires a JSON array"` It's like I need to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TApiModel[]>(data.Select(d => d.data)).FirstOrDefault().ConvertToBaseModel()` but obviously I can't because data is a string at that point. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that `data: ` at the beginning (BTW, it's `"Data":`, but that's just nitpicking...) In that case, you can reflect that in your type, or use ekke's answer, or `DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<TApiModel>>>...` any of these ways should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled that is working now with that type. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had issues in which the data model gets wrapped in an addition object like in your example. One solution which worked for me with fairly minimal changes was the wrap the TModel class in a dictionary.

So your line here would become:

```
var deserializedObjectDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, new Dictionary<string, List<TApiModel>>());
// now unwrap dictionary to extract object
```

It's a little inelegant but often it's the best solution if you don't want to add additional model classes.

Comment: I ended up opting for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<TApiModel>>>(data)` as suggested by Zohar in the comments. I am accepting this as the answer because the `Dictionary<string, List<TApiModel>>` ultimately was the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing that now I am getting a `dictionary<string, List>`, I can use `GetValueOrDefault('data')` to explicitly get the value I need from that key:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<TApiModel>>>(data).GetValueOrDefault("data").FirstOrDefault().ConvertToBaseModel();
```